# Потеря контекста у функции как метода объекта

Tags: javascript, this, context

Почему если функция вызванная как метод объекта в качестве колбэка например в setTimeout не теряет свой контекст. Например:

```
Let user = {
 name: “Саша”,
 sayHi() {
   alert(`Привет,${this.name}`
 }
}

setTimeout(() => user.sayHi(), 1000)
```

Почему контекст не теряется если this у setTimeout ссылается на window???

Comment: а почему она должна терять контекст? метод же вызван у конкретного объекта

Comment: А тогда почему если ее вызвать просто без обертки то контекст теряется:

Comment: setTimeout(user.sayHi, 1000) выводит просто привет без this.name

Comment: в вопросе в коде ты **вызываешь метод** у объекта, в коде в комментарии ты **НЕ вызываешь метод**, а передаёшь ссылку на него.... смекаешь?))

Comment: Дело в том, что в колбэк передаётся функция которая вызывает именно метод у объекта. Поэтому контекст не теряется. А если вы передадите метод в колбэк таким образом setTimeout(user.sayHi, 1000) , тогда контекст будет потерян

Comment: Я понял насчёт вызвать метод и передать ссылку на метод,спасибо. Но мне не понятно почему если я вызываю метод в setTimeout внутри колбэка он работает как надо а если вызвать метод просто без колбэка вот так например setTimeout(user.sayHi(),1000) он контекст не теряет но работает без задержки? Это особенность setTimeout такая что ли?

Comment: "setTimeout(user.sayHi(),1000) он контекст не теряет но работает без задержки" --- в setTimeout надо передавать функцию, ты же тут сразу вызываешь метод (функцию)....

Comment: Если я правильно понял. setTimeout  должна получить функцию, и значит если внутри неё вызвать метод то он не теряет контекст так как получается что то на подобии замыкания и контекст сохраняется.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, вроде бы дошло )))